# wpf databinding with Delay property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have specified a `TextBox` with Delay set to 100 as follows:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox" 
     Grid.Column="1"
     PreviewKeyDown="SearchTextBox_PreviewKeyDown"
     KeyUp="SearchTextBox_KeyUp" 
     Margin="0,2,0,0" FontSize="14" 
     Padding="3" 
     Text="{Binding Path=SearchText, Delay=100, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

I have an event wired up for `KeyUp`, my idea is when the user hits the Enter Key i want to perform something.

Sometimes I have noticed that when I hit Enter, the whole text is NOT being updated in the property `SearchText` in my ViewModel, is it because the binding has not yet updated by the time I hit ENTER? because of the delay? Is there a way around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the key handler you could make sure that the binding is updated by [getting the binding expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getbindingexpression.aspx) for the `Text` binding and calling [`UpdateSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource.aspx) first.